# Spring boot - WeatherApp - API

Tags: java, spring, api

Im trying to make weather apps with spring boot MVC. I wanted to use api from: openweather.com.

In the controller I have a method to pass the parameter. I have two html pages. One with form and submit, the other to display the string of the form.
How to bind an API with my parameter from a form and how to retrieve JSON information.

```
@GetMapping("/show")
public String show(@RequestParam ("city") String city, ModelMap modelMap){
    modelMap.addAttribute("city", city);
    return "article/show";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RestTemplate` to retrieve JSON from weather API.

You have an example on link below:
http://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

After you receive the JSON object then you can add it to the model and send it to JSP or some other templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a get listener in your back-end code that will get the weather from openweather. It should look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/weather")
public String show(@RequestParam ("city") String city)
//Method body
//In the method body you should make a request to the openweather server with an api key which you can get by registering in the website. You can achieve this with Unirest library (it's the easiest way)
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather")/
                            .queryString("APPID","YOUR_APP_ID")
                            .queryString("city",city)
                            .header("content-type","application/json")
                            .asJson();
```

This method will return a JSON with all the data you need, which you can parse with RestTemplate.